# Unicode errors on zope security proxied objects

Tags: python, zope

Ok, so the general background for this question is that I'm trying to make a custom dictionary class that will create a string representation of the dictionary which is just a lookup of one of the values (which are all unicode values). In the real code, depending on some internal logic, one of the keys is chosen as the current default for the lookup, so that `unicode(dict_obj)` will return a single value within the dictionary such as `u'Some value'` or if the value doesn't exist for the current default key: `u'None'`

This functionality is working no problem. The real problem lies when using it within the application from the zope page templates which wrap the object in a security proxy. The proxied object doesn't behave the same as the original object.

Here is the boiled down code of the custom dictionary class:

```
class IDefaultKeyDict(Interface):

    def __unicode__():
        """Create a unicode representation of the dictionary."""

    def __str__():
        """Create a string representation of the dictionary."""


class DefaultKeyDict(dict):
    """A custom dictionary for handling default values"""
    implements(IDefaultKeyDict)

    def __init__(self, default, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DefaultKeyDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._default = default

    def __unicode__(self):
        print "In DefaultKeyDict.__unicode__"
        key = self.get_current_default()
        result = self.get(key)
        return unicode(result)

    def __str__(self):
        print "In DefaultKeyDict.__str__"
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')

    def get_current_default(self):
        return self._default
```

And the associated zcml permissions for this class:

```
<class class=".utils.DefaultKeyDict">
  <require
    interface=".utils.IDefaultKeyDict" 
    permission="zope.View" />
</class>
```

I've left the print statements in both the `__unicode__` and `__str__` methods to show the different behavior with the proxied objects. So creating a dummy dictionary class with a pre-defined default key:

```
>>> dummy = DefaultKeyDict(u'key2', {u'key1': u'Normal ascii text', u'key2': u'Espa\xf1ol'})
>>> dummy
{u'key2': u'Espa\xf1ol', u'key1': u'Normal ascii text'}
>>> str(dummy)
In DefaultKeyDict.__str__
In DefaultKeyDict.__unicode__
'Espa\xc3\xb1ol'
>>> unicode(dummy)
In DefaultKeyDict.__unicode__
u'Espa\xf1ol'
>>> print dummy
In DefaultKeyDict.__str__
In DefaultKeyDict.__unicode__
Español
```

Everything works as expected. Now I can wrap the object in a security proxy from the `zope.security` package and do the same tests to show the error:

```
>>> from zope.security.checker import ProxyFactory
>>> prox = ProxyFactory(dummy)
>>> prox
{u'key2': u'Espa\xf1ol', u'key1': u'Normal ascii text'}
>>> type(prox)
<type 'zope.security._proxy._Proxy'>
>>> str(prox)
In DefaultKeyDict.__str__
In DefaultKeyDict.__unicode__
'Espa\xc3\xb1ol'
>>> unicode(prox)
In DefaultKeyDict.__str__
In DefaultKeyDict.__unicode__
*** UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

As you can see, calling `unicode` on the proxied object isn't possible anymore if it contains any special characters. I can see the proxy object from `zope.security` is mostly defined with C code and I'm not familiar at all with the C Python API, but it seems that the `__str__` and `__repr__` methods are defined in the C code but not `__unicode__`. So to me, what seems to be happening is that when it is trying to create a unicode representation of this proxied object, instead of calling the `__unicode__` method directly, it calls the `__str__` method (as you can see from the last few print statements above), which returns a `utf-8` encoded byte string, but that is then being converted to unicode (using the default ascii encoding). So what is happening seems to be the equivalent of this:

```
>>> unicode(prox.__str__())
In DefaultKeyDict.__str__
In DefaultKeyDict.__unicode__
*** UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So of course it will result in a UnicodeDecodeError in this case, trying to decode a `utf-8` string with ascii. As expected, if I could specify the encoding of `utf-8` there wouldn't be a problem.

```
>>> unicode(prox.__str__(), encoding='utf-8')
In DefaultKeyDict.__str__
In DefaultKeyDict.__unicode__
u'Espa\xf1ol'
```

But I can't change that since we are talking about the `zope.pagetemplate` and `zope.tales` packages that are creating the unicode representation out of all types of objects, and they always seem to be working with the security proxied objects (from `zope.security`). Also of note, there is no problem calling the `__unicode__` method directly on the object.

```
>>> prox.__unicode__()
In DefaultKeyDict.__unicode__
u'Espa\xf1ol'
```

So the real problem is that `unicode(prox)` calls the `__str__` method. I've been spinning my wheels on this for a while and don't know where else to go now. Any insights would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your analysis is correct and the wrapper doesn't support a Unicode hook; partly because the *python 2 C-API never defined a slot for it*. The wrapper has to define a `__unicode__` attribute on the type and that'll have to handle the case where the wrapped object has no such hook itself. Tricky, which is probably why it hasn't been addressed yet.

Comment: This is certainly a bug; the Python-implementation does handle `__unicode__`; only the C implementation is missing it. Feel free to report it as such at https://bugs.launchpad.net/zope.security

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the insight into the python C-API. That does make it trickier than I initially thought. At least for now, the bug is reported at https://bugs.launchpad.net/zope.security/+bug/1367566 I later found a related bug already reported in the `zope.proxy` package, but looks to be a different C implementation of the proxy class. https://bugs.launchpad.net/zope.proxy/+bug/1262702

Answer (score 0):

Judging by what you've said about the C API defining `__str__` and `__repr__` methods but not `__unicode__` methods, I suspect whatever C library you're using has been written to be compatible with python 3. I'm not familiar with zope, but I'm relatively confident this should be the case.

> In Python 2, the object model specifies **str**() and  **unicode**()
>   methods. If these methods exist, they must return str (bytes) and
>   unicode (text) respectively.
>
> In Python 3, there’s simply **str**(), which must return str (text).

I may be slightly missing the point with your program but do you really need the `__unicode__` method defined? As you've said everything in the dict is belonging to the unicode character set. So calling the `__str__` method will decode that into utf-8, and if you wanted to see the binaries for the string why not just `encode` it?

Note that `decode()` returns a string object, whilst `encode()` returns a bytes object.

If you could, please post an edit/comment so I can understand a little bit more what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well the C library is written to be compatible with both Python 2 and 3. I see some of the definitions within a block of `#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION < 3` with a comment above it saying for Python 2 compatibility. However, it seems that the **unicode()** compatibility for Python 2 was left out of it.

Comment: The main problem here is that the code is dealing with a third party zope package that is used for rendering the python objects as HTML code. It expects to be able to retrieve a unicode representation of an object and I can't change that. One of the problems of dealing with encoded byte strings in the logic of a program is that the type of encoding can be lost. So right now, the behavior (and the problem) is that the string is being encoded to utf-8, then it is passed to a 3rd party package that doesn't know what encoding it is, and attempts to decode it with the system default which is ascii.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to be a problem very specific to the interaction of these zope package with my custom object.

Comment: The OP is using Python 2 where `__unicode__` definitely is needed and supported. But special methods like `__unicode__` are looked up on the type, and the proxy wrapper doesn't implement this hook (and there is no C-API equivalent, making this harder).

Comment: The proxy was originally written for Python 2; Python 3 support was added later on. The codebase predates Python 3 by some years. And Unicode support in Python was still in its infancy too, if I recall my timelines correctly. It is absolutely not the case that it was written for just Python 3, *far from it*.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is looking for a temporary solution to this problem, I can share the monkeypatch fixes that we've implemented. Patching these two methods from `zope.tal` and `zope.tales` seems to do the trick.  This will work well as long as you know that the encoding will always be `utf-8`.

```
from zope.tal import talinterpreter

def do_insertStructure_tal(self, (expr, repldict, block)):
    """Patch for zope.security proxied I18NDicts.

    The Proxy wrapper doesn't support a unicode hook for now. The only way to
    fix this is to monkey patch this method which calls 'unicode'.
    """
    structure = self.engine.evaluateStructure(expr)
    if structure is None:
        return
    if structure is self.Default:
        self.interpret(block)
        return
    if isinstance(structure, talinterpreter.I18nMessageTypes):
        text = self.translate(structure)
    else:
        try:
            text = unicode(structure)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            text = unicode(str(structure), encoding='utf-8')
    if not (repldict or self.strictinsert):
        # Take a shortcut, no error checking
        self.stream_write(text)
        return
    if self.html:
        self.insertHTMLStructure(text, repldict)
    else:
        self.insertXMLStructure(text, repldict)
talinterpreter.TALInterpreter.do_insertStructure_tal = do_insertStructure_tal
talinterpreter.TALInterpreter.bytecode_handlers_tal["insertStructure"] = \
    do_insertStructure_tal
```

and this one:

```
from zope.tales import tales


def evaluateText(self, expr):
    """Patch for zope.security proxied I18NDicts.

    The Proxy wrapper doesn't support a unicode hook for now. The only way to
    fix this is to monkey patch this method which calls 'unicode'.
    """
    text = self.evaluate(expr)
    if text is self.getDefault() or text is None:
        return text
    if isinstance(text, basestring):
        # text could already be something text-ish, e.g. a Message object
        return text
    try:
        return unicode(text)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return unicode(str(text), encoding='utf-8')
tales.Context.evaluateText = evaluateText
```